# Demod as a neologism

Tags: word-usage, etymology, expressions

***[Moderator](https://www.etymonline.com/word/moderator)*** is a very old term in the sense still popularly used nowadays:

> - Meaning "one who acts as an arbitrator, person who presides at a meeting or disputation" is from 1560s. (Etymonline)

***[Demod](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=demod)***, a neologism so frequently used in recent weeks virtually on all SE sites, appears only in Urban Dictionary in a scarcely   visited entry which dates  to 2005.

> - Altering the moderator into a member

Other in-between terms like “demoderate” or “demoderated” show no usage instances, so it appears that the construction is derived directly from the abbreviation “mod”.

Was  “mod” introduced with the growth of web sites an the proliferation of “moderators”, or was it used before the internet era? (I tried Google Books but with no success). When was demod  coined?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99727/discussion-on-question-by-user067531-demod-as-a-neologism).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like the OP, I first discovered this unusual expression on Stack Exchange.

Moderators on Stack Exchange are not employees, they are volunteers who have [special privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100153/223820) and powers that help them *moderate* a community. They are identifiable by the diamond ♦ next to their username, and they have either been appointed by the company or elected by their peers. Moderators generally hold their position for life but they are free to resign at any time they please.

Under egregious circumstances, the company may decide to strip a moderator of their privileges, this has lead users to say that a mod was *fired* (AmEng), *sacked* (BrEng) or *dismissed* but these terms imply that the moderator was a paid employee; nothing could be further from the truth. As a result, the act of [*demotion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demotion) or *[degrading](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/degrade)* a moderator is called  **demodding**, and to be downgraded is *to be demodded*.

Searching online, there is an example of its early usage, dated **October 10, 2004**, in [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=DanSTC), under the entry of **DanSTC**

> DanSTC, when will you learn that nobody respected you or thought your opinions mattered before and after you were **demodded** and banned?

From **January 17, 2005**

> Ok, The Reason I Want Stryder Out Of Admin is because he **demods** me from media because i do the simpleest mastakes known to life on earth, ok today 1.16.2005 I got **demodded** from media, ok here is the reason, I asked dan why we couldnt have HTML he said it was Dangoues i kept asking y is it Dangoues he said nvm each time, so i tell him I am going to make a poll about it in Rants/Raves (By The Way Where Anything Goes) So I Go Making A Poll, If lndforums.com should have html off or on and about 10-20 minutes later on Msn he goes and says your **Demodded**, i mean 4 gods sake he didn't even give me a warning, so can you please sign this petiton to help me get rid of stryder from admin, I'd Really Like It If You Would Sign This Pentiton!
>   By Stephen
>
> *[GoPetition.com](https://www.gopetition.com/petitions/get-rid-of-stryder-himoutta-admin.html)*

The term “mod” can also be modified with a different prefix re-, as in **remodded**. The citation below is dated February 2019

> When the new discord was created, Nermal joined and eventually became a new mod after proving himself. He was promoted as a full mod until March 11th where he was **demodded** for a short period of time for homophobia. He was **remodded** by Kirbizia, which was one of the only times Kirbizia was in the right.

*[dogelore.fandom.Wikipedia](https://dogelore.fandom.com/wiki/Nermal)*.

---

- Glossary
  Dangoues = a typo or misspelling of *dangerous*
  y = why
  nvm = nevermind
  4 gods sake = for god's sake

Comment: Would the spelled-out form of this verb (in past tense) be _demoderatored_ or _demoderated_ or something else? The focus of the term certainly seems to be "removed from the position of moderator" (hence "demoderatored") rather than say "stopped from moderating" (hence "demoderated"). That is, it seems to hinge on removal from an official position rather than from performing certain actions. But perhaps there is a more nuanced sense of the term that I'm not aware of.